# What is the usual definition of a proof?

Tags: first-order-logic

[image]

I saw this on a book. It says, $X$ is provable if every branch(connected by $\vee$) of $\sim X$ implies contradiction.

However, I thought that a proof is a sequence of formulas $p_n$, where each $p_n$ either is an axiom or 'follows' from $p_{m_1}=q$ and $p_{m_2}=q\to p_n$ for some $m_1,m_2<n$.

I am also comfused by the quantificational rules:

[image]

$A_\alpha^x$ means the formula constructed by replacing all 'free' $x$ with $a$. 'with proviso' means that $a$ does not occur in $A$, I guess.

It seems that I can not use De Morgan's laws here, since then there will be $\frac{A_\alpha^x}{(\exists x )A}$  and $\frac{(\forall x )A}{(\exists x )A}$ which are definitely not correct, right?

Comment: I believe the book is Smullyan's _First-order Logic_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different proof systems, which give rise to different definitions of a proof. What the definition of a proof is depends on which proof system you are talking about.

The definition of proof as a sequence of formulas etc. is what you get for axiomatic proof systems, where you have a bunch of axioms and few inference rules and combine them to a linear shaped proof with one inference step per line.

The tableau calculus is a different proof system. There are no axioms in the tableau calculus. Also a tableau proof is not a linear sequence, but a tree. And the proof strategy is not a direct proof of the conclusion, but proof by refutation, i.e. starting with the assumption that the conclusion does not hold and deriving a contradiction from that assumption.

Since proofs look different in the tableau calculus vs. an axiomatic proof system, the definition of a proof in that system is a different one. Neither of the two definitions of a proof is wrong; they just talk about different proof systems.

And yes, you can not use De Morgan's laws in a tableau proof, because there is no De Morgan rule in the tableau calculus. Everything is derived from the positive and negative rules for each connective.
But the tableau calculus is complete, meaning that every valid inference can be derived in it, so you will be able to find a tableau proof of the De Morgan laws using the A, B, C and D rules. E.g. to prove $\neg \forall x A(x) \vdash \exists x \neg A(x)$ in the tableau system, you start by assuming $\neg \forall x A(x)$ and $\neg \exists x \neg A(x)$, infer $\neg A(a)$ from the first assumption with rule D and $\neg \neg A(a)$ from the second one with rule C, which gets you the contradiction $\neg A(a), \neg \neg A(a)$, thereby completing the single-branch proof.

I don't know how you arrive at the deductions in your last paragraph, but yes, they are not proofs in the tableau system, because they don't match the rules of the tableau calculus.

The motivation behind the C rules is that if you know that $A$ holds of all $x$, it holds of whatever $a$ you insert for $x$. The idea of the D rules is that if $A$ holds of some $x$, you can give that object which you know exists a name and insert that name for $x$, provided you don't make any additional assumptions about that object by identifying it with some other previously introduced name of which other sentences are already established to hold. The proviso is that  $a$ is new in the sense that is does not yet occur in any formulas on the branch (not just not in $A$). An analogous reasoning applies to the negated quantifiers.

Comment: Doesn't Rule C mean $A_a^x$ 'implies' $(\forall x) A$ ?

Comment: No, it means that from $\forall x A$ we are allowed to infer $A_a^x$. The inference goes the other way round, and it is not implication in the semantic sense (although the rules is of course motivated by the semantics), but a simple rewrite rule: If you have the string of symbols $\forall x A$ written on one line, you are allowed to write down $A_a^x$ for some $a$ on a line beneath it.

Comment: @Yuz I added a paragraph on the motivation behind the quantifier rules.